# null pointer exception at the parameters passed to an inner method in unit testing

Tags: android, unit-testing

The `State` is a `enum` inside MyClass.class with 3 different states {Registered, Unregistered, Uninitialized}

Inside EventListener.class

```
private MyClass.State mystate;
```

The `list` to hold the `listeners`

```
private static List<StatusListener> mStatusListenerList
        = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<StatusListener>());
```

The method to register the `listener`

```
 public static void registerListener(final StatusListener statusListener) {
    mStatusListenerList.add(statusListener);
}
```

The method to deregister the `listener`

```
public static void deRegisterListener(final StatusListener statusListener) {
    mStatusListenerList.remove(statusListener);
}
```

The onStateChanged method for which i need to do the unit test

```
@Override
public void onStateChanged(final MyClass.State state) {
    LOG.i(" onStateChanged - State = " + state);
    mystate = state;
    notifyListeners(state);
}
```

This is the method which notifies all the registered `listeners`

`onstatuschanged` is an `interface` method

```
public void notifyListeners(final MyClass.State state) {
    for (StatusListener StatusListener
            : mStatusListenerList) {
        StatusListener.onStatusChanged(state);
    }
}
```

The StatusListener interface is

```
public interface StatusListener {

void onStatusChanged(final MyClass.State state);
}
```

Inside EventListenerTest.class

Variable Declaration

```
 private List<StatusListener> mStatusListenerList
        = new LinkedList<StatusListener>();
```

My test method for the notifyListeners() method is

```
@Test
public void testNotifyListener() {
    mStatusListenerList.add(PowerMockito.mock(StatusListener.class));

    for (StatusListener statusListener
            : mStatusListenerList) {
        Mockito.doNothing().when(statusListener).
                onStatusChanged(MyClass.State.Registered);
    }

    EventListener.notifyListeners(MyClass.State.Registered,
            mStatusListenerList);

    Mockito.verify(mStatusListenerList.get(0), times(1)).
            onStatusChanged(MyClass.State.Registered);
    }
}
```

my test method for onStateChanged() is

```
@Test
public void testOnStateChanged() {
EventListener eventListener;
    mStatusListenerList.add(PowerMockito.mock(StatusListener.class));
    Mockito.doNothing().when(Mockito.mock(EventListener.class)).
            notifyListeners(MyClass.State.Registered, mStatusListenerList);
    //Test
    EventListener.onStateChanged(MyClass.State.Registered);

    assertEquals(MyClass.State.Registered,
            EventListener.getEventState());
}
```

The above test throws a null pointer exception near the parameters passed to the notify listeners method

Comment: Have you tried to write unit test?

Comment: Show the actual stack trace.

Comment: com.example.EventListenerTest > testOnStateChanged FAILED
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.EventListener.notifyListeners(EventListener.java:443)
        at com.example.EventListener.onStateChanged(EventListener.java:433)
        at com.example.EventListenerTest.testOnStateChanged(EventListenerTest.java:229)